# How to check FormGroup inputs Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have this code in component:

```
this.loginForm = this._fb.group({
      phone: ['', [<any>Validators.required, <any>Validators.minLength(5)]],
      password: ['', [<any>Validators.required, <any>Validators.minLength(7)]]
    });
```

In form I tried to show message if input is invalid:

```
<small [hidden]="loginForm.controls.phone.invalid || (loginForm.controls.phone.pristine && !submitted)" class="text-danger">
```

But it does not work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're having contradict condition on `hidden`, it should be

```
<small 
  [hidden]="loginForm.controls?.phone?.valid || (loginForm.controls?.phone?.pristine && !submitted)" 
  class="text-danger">
```

But rather I'd suggest you to use `ngClass`(with `hide` class)/`ngIf` directive here which will add or remove `hide` class based on expression provided to it.

```
<small *ngIf="loginForm.controls.phone?.invalid || (loginForm.controls.phone?.pristine && !submitted)" class="text-danger">
```

Comment: This `loginForm.controls.phone.pristine` gives me an error: `undefined phone`

Comment: Maybe use `loginForm.controls['phone'].pristine`?

Comment: Can you provide me a plunker?

Comment: An you provide me a plunker Please?